# How to update an ios App with current information daily

Tags: ios

I'm trying to design an app for my club at school. What I want to happen is when there is new information about meetings or events I want to be able to add this new content to the app and then have it visible by other app users.

So my question is how would I approach this idea?

Comment: Use a server to host the data.

Comment: .... then have your app ask the server for that data on a schedule or whenever the data is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you're going to need to have a centralized server which contains the data, an API to connect an application to this data, and finally the end user application.

On the server end, you could have a simple database which will house the event and meeting information.

On the API end, you could have a simple script which fetches the latest entries in the database and displays the data in a standard format such as JSON or XML.

On the app end, every time the user opens the application, fetch the latest data from your API and parse it into an array.  Then, just populate a table or collection with the data in that array.  You could also add a pull to refresh control to fetch the latest information at any time so the user doesn't have to launch the app again.